# How to remove minimum api 23 permission

Tags: java, android

Yesterday, I updated things on my app to improve ease of use so as to align with the success brought about by trend of technology.
I was trying to set external storage permission to read file from root. After the setting It requires that I should set minimum target api to 23. The gradle file also require that I set minimum SDK to 23.

My problem now is this setting will completely disengage my app users with devices below Marshmallow,
Please help me with correction so I can be able to set minimum SDK to 17.

```
@TargetApi(23)
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2000:
                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap();
                perms.put("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", Integer.valueOf(0));
                perms.put("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", Integer.valueOf(0));
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                        perms.put(permissions[i], Integer.valueOf(grantResults[i]));
                    }
                    if (((Integer) perms.get("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")).intValue() == 0 && ((Integer) perms.get("android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")).intValue() == 0) {
                        if (this.blnStart) {
                            callnext();
                            return;
                        } else if (this.blnMyCreation) {
                            callmycreation();
                            return;
                        } else {
                            return;
                        }
                    } else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")) {
                        showDialogOK("Permission required for this app", new NewGlobe());
                        return;
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                return;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: for what reason `The gradle file also require that I set minimum SDK to 23`

Comment: _"I got some error"_ It's impossible for anyone to offer any advice regarding that until you say exactly what the error was.

Comment: tell me what to do to have that permission re-written to use minimum SDK 17

Comment: We can't tell you without the full information. Why does it require a bump to 23 in gradle? If that's the case there is no real need to target that api anyway.

Comment: Oh sorry I got it all wrong. Thanks for your questions anyway. help me close this question